# Why doesn't a trailing tab typeset?

Tags: spacing, tex-core

Consider the following Plain TeX manuscript

```
\catcode9=12\relax% ASCII 9 is tab
.\ \ .\par%
.   
.%
\bye
```

It's impossible to tell, but there's a tab just after the dot on the third manuscript line. To make sure, here's the byte content of the file (each byte is represented by a two-digit hexadecimal number):

[image: Byte content of file.]

You can see the tab represented as the hex number `09` on the second line.

This manuscript typesets thus:

```
.  .
. .
```

Observe that there seem to be two spaces between the dots on the first line, but only one space between the dots on the second line.

However, I'd expect there two be two spaces between the dots on the second line too: one for the tab, and one for the carriage-return at the end of the line.

One way to explain this was suggested by egreg in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104050) (to a different question), which says:

> TeX reads one record at a time (a line in the input file, more or less) and discards the end-of-record terminator along with all spaces or tabs that immediately precede this end-of-record

This implies that the tab character is never seen by the TeX engine's "stomach", which explains the typeset outcome.

However this quote is not supported by the TeXbook (20th printing, Addison-Wesley 1991), as far as the tab character is concerned. Indeed, the TeXbook describes the same stage of the processing thus (p. 46):

> TeX deletes any `<space>` characters (number 32) that occur at the right end of an input line.

Note the specification of the number 32, which is ASCII space.

The TeX source code for the input routine (viz. `input_ln`, defined in section 31, p. 16 of `texdoc tex`) is also quite particular about trailing *spaces*:

> Trailing blanks are removed from the line; thus, either `last=first` (in which case the line was entirely blank) or `buffer[last − 1]≠"␣"`.

So why is there only a single space between the dots on the second typeset line?

---

Incidentally, if the font is changed to `cmtt`, e.g.:

```
\font\myfont=cmtt14\myfont%
\catcode9=12%
.\ \ .\par%
.   
.%
\bye
```

the distances between the two dots on both lines are the same, however, as Steven B. Segletes' [experiment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389030/why-doesnt-a-trailing-tab-typeset#comment965165_389030) shows, the tab is not seen by the engine's "stomach".

Comment: You mean a tab at the end of the _third_ line, don't you?

Comment: Adding an empty group,`{}`, to the end of the 3rd line produces the extra space in the output, so clearly the tab and the end-of-line are being digested as a single space.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: But why?

Comment: Page 8 TeXbook?  "TEX is
initially set up to treat  `\<return>` and `\<tab>` the same as `\ `  (control space);"

Comment: Page 45 TeXbook?  "The control code `^^I` is also of potential interest, since it’s the ASCII <tab>.
Plain TEX makes <tab> act like a blank space."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: But (essentially) the same program typesets the same way when Plain TeX is not loaded, not to mention that the tab's catcode is set to 12 in the beginning of the manuscript.

Comment: But with a `\catcode` of 12, wouldn't it act like `\relax` (a token that does nothing), since it has no glyph (nor space) associated with it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Your own experiment suggested in your first comment shows that it does not act like `\relax`.

Comment: TeXbook, pp.369-370: "A completely permissive version of TEX allows full 256-character input and output; other
versions might ignore all but the visible characters of ASCII; still other versions might
distinguish the tab character (code ´011 ) from a space on input, but might output each
tab as a sequence of three characters ^^I."  Also on p.391: "We shall assume that files can contain a special symbol that TEX will input
as character number 9, the ASCII <tab> code; some implementations can’t actually do
this."  Page 391 seems particularly instructive on the <tab>

Comment: If you start out the file with `\catcode` ` `\^^I=\active %
\gdef^^I{X}`, you will see that none of the tabs in the input are actually intercepted and converted to `X`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Some hypothetical versions might ignore all but the visible characters. Some hypothetical implementations might not  be able input a tab. But all the actual implementations of TeX are able to input tab and to distinguish between space and tab.

Comment: @EvanAad Can you clarify why you think that “all the actual implementations of TeX are able to […] distinguish between space and tab”?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I should have said "all the actual implementations of TeX that I'm aware of", or better yet: "the implementation that I used to compile the manuscript with can input a tab".

Comment: @EvanAad Ok, which implementations did you try, and what evidence do you have that that they distinguish between space and tab, rather than treating a tab as a space? Can you make it more clear? For example, does `\catcode9=\active` (equivalent to `\catcode9=13`) have any effect in any of the implementations you tried?

Comment: Also, try with `a` and `b` instead of `.` and `.` (note that TeX treats punctuation as special).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Very curious. TeX is not supposed to handle punctuation any differently than letters, in this context. Indeed, if instead of `a` and `b` you use two commas, you'll see a difference in the distances just like you see with `a` and `b`.

Comment: Basically, there are (at least) four matters here [with the answers I think, in brackets]: (1) what TeX does when it reads a line [strips trailing spaces but not tabs] (2) *after reading in lines,* how TeX treats tabs [same as spaces] (3) how the visual width of a space is affected by the font (monospace versus regular fonts) (4) how TeX treats punctuation (frenchspacing versus nonfrenchspacing, spacefactor, etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64841/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-shreevatsar).

Comment: BTW just noticed this duplicate(!) question: [Which TeX procedure removes trailing tabs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66498/which-tex-procedure-removes-trailing-tabs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some code findings for the "folklore" of egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389084/16967).

TeX removes "blanks" at the end of an input line. This is done at a very early stage, just after reading the line before considering category codes and the
input characters get tokenized.

Originally, these "blanks" are spaces only, but TeX distributions like TeX Live or MiKTeX extends them to include tabulators (horizontal tabulator).
The snippets show the behavior for TeX, and pdfTeX. Not shown are XeTeX and LuaTeX that also remove spaces and tabulators at the end of input lines.

The code snippets come from TeX Live (2016).

- `texk/web2c/tex.web`:

  ```pascal
  @ The |input_ln| function brings the next line of input from the specified
  file [...]
  Trailing blanks are removed from the line;
  [...]
  @p function input_ln(var f:alpha_file;@!bypass_eoln:boolean):boolean;
    {inputs the next line or returns |false|}
  var last_nonblank:0..buf_size; {|last| with trailing blanks removed}
  begin if bypass_eoln then if not eof(f) then get(f);
    {input the first character of the line into |f^|}
  last:=first; {cf.\ Matthew 19\thinspace:\thinspace30}
  if eof(f) then input_ln:=false
  else  begin last_nonblank:=first;
    while not eoln(f) do
      begin if last>=max_buf_stack then
        begin max_buf_stack:=last+1;
        if max_buf_stack=buf_size then
          @<Report overflow of the input buffer, and abort@>;
        end;
      buffer[last]:=xord[f^]; get(f); incr(last);
      if buffer[last-1]<>" " then last_nonblank:=last;
      end;
    last:=last_nonblank; input_ln:=true;
    end;
  end;
  ```

  The original TeX only removes spaces at the end of an input line.
  However, the Pascal version of `input_ln` will be overwritten by a
  more efficient C version, see the next code snippets.
- `texk/web2c/tex.ch` is a change file for `tex.web`:

  ```pascal
  @x [3.31] l.933 - Do `input_ln' in C.
  @p function input_ln(var f:alpha_file;@!bypass_eoln:boolean):boolean;
  [...]
  end;
  @y
  We define |input_ln| in C, for efficiency. [...]
  @z
  ```
- `texk/web2c/lib/texmfmp.c`:

  ```c
  /* Read a line of input as efficiently as possible while still looking
     like Pascal.  We set `last' to `first' and return `false' if we get
     to eof.  Otherwise, we return `true' and set last = first +
     length(line except trailing whitespace).  */

  #ifndef XeTeX /* for XeTeX, we have a replacement function in XeTeX_ext.c */
  boolean
  input_line (FILE *f)
  {
    [...]

    /* Trim trailing whitespace.  */
    while (last > first && ISBLANK (buffer[last - 1]))
      --last;

    [...]
  }
  ```
- `texk/kpathsea/c-ctype.h`:

  ```c
  #ifndef isblank
  #define isblank(c) ((c) == ' ' || (c) == '\t')
  #endif

  #define ISBLANK(c) (isascii (c) && isblank ((unsigned char)c))
  ```

  `isblank` tests for space and tabulators, therefore *both* are removed
  at the end of an input line.
- `texk/web2c/ChangeLog`:

  ```
  Thu Oct 16 20:39:27 1997  Olaf Weber  <...>

      * `tex.ch`: [...]  Also, various changes
      for e-TeX (small rearrangements, introduces Init..Tini, remove
      tabs and trailing blanks).  From Peter Breitenlohner
      <...>.
  ```

  The change is very old, two decades ago in the last century.

Comment: Thank you. I've submitted a bug report to TeX Live. From your answer it looks like it will be a piece of cake to fix, if there's any desire to do so.

Comment: @EvanAad I do not know the reason, why tabulators are also removed at the end of an input line. But, since the main TeX distributions (TeX Live and MiKTeX) and its TeX compilers (TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX) behave the same way, I have some doubts that this will be "fixed".

Comment: There are also arguments for the removal of tabulators. Like the space, it is an invisible horizontal white space character. Most editors will not show them. LaTeX and plain TeX assign the tabulator the category code of a space. Then a tabulator at the line end with the line end might cause *two* spaces (a little difficult to test). This would be also a cause for a "bug report".

Comment: Good reasons, but do you think Knuth was unaware of them when he specified that only trailing spaces should be removed? I don't understand your last point. A tab followed by a carriage return will, under normal circumstances, result in only at most a single space, as per the usual rules for spaces.

Comment: @EvanAad I found a test by using a different character with category code 10, they get merged with the end of line (category code 5).

Comment: I have a guess that it's even older than 1997; probably dating to the late 80s or early 90s when `web2c` was written. I think the “remove tabs and trailing blanks” comment in the ChangeLog may be about tabs and trailing blanks being removed in the `tex.ch` file itself.

Comment: @Evan There are changes to the TeX engine and the TeX book every once in a while. An almost thirty year old book about software tends to be not 100% correct anymore.

Answer (score 10):

The file I used is

```
\catcode9=12

.
.       %
.
\bye
```

Line 3 has `.<tab>`, line 4 has `.<tab>%`, line 5 has `.<tab><space>`

```bsh
> hexdump tabs.tex 
0000000 5c 63 61 74 63 6f 64 65 39 3d 31 32 0a 0a 2e 09
0000010 0a 2e 09 25 0a 2e 09 20 0a 5c 62 79 65 0a      
000001e
```

This is what `pdftex` typesets:

[image]

Only the `<tab>` followed by `%` survives, because TeX Live implementations of TeX remove trailing spaces *and* tabs from lines, irrespective of their catcodes. I tried to find the reference, but apparently this is to be considered folklore.

The space between the first two periods is added by the end-of-line.

## Update 2019

With the 2019 release of TeX Live, the TeX engines no longer remove traling tab tokens, but only spaces and the output you get is

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion, this constitutes a bug in the TeX Live implementation, considering that both the TeXbook and the TeX source code are particular about removing trailing *spaces* from the end of the line. Do you agree? Should I open a bug report?

Comment: @EvanAad This has been like this for several years.

Comment: @EvenAad: I agree it's technically a bug, but I suspect it's unlikely to get fixed.  It would be interesting to have the original implementers chime in why they took this decision decades ago.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: I get the rationale. It's the same reason why `<space>` and `<tab>` are given the same catcode in Plain TeX. I mean, trailing spaces and trailing tabs are virtually indistinguishable. Nevertheless, it's safe to assume that this was not beyond Knuth's awareness when he wrote the code, and yet he chose to specify that only trailing spaces should be discarded. Shouldn't his specs be respected? Alternatively, maybe he can be convinced to change the specs.

Comment: @EvanAad Possibly not here: dropping end of line whitespace of any form would have been my call. Not tested with vertical tabs or whatever, but one can see the logic.

Comment: @JosephWright: IMO, at least `tex`, if not the other engines, should be as true to Knuth's intentions as possible.

Comment: @JosephWright: So I checked with a vertical tab, and it works as Knuth intended, i.e. it typesets, as seen in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4xzZ.png).

Comment: @egreg Turns out this question has been asked and answered on this site before :-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66498/which-tex-procedure-removes-trailing-tabs

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I remembered it already came up in one of my questions but had forgotten I had actually asked the exact same question and I forgot Lev Bishop's answer.

Comment: @egreg: I tried to replicate your example file using real TAB, but, I don't get the same output `.Ψ .Ψ.Ψ`,  using `pdftex` (TeXLive 2019).

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL With TL 2019, trailing tabs are no longer removed.

Comment: @egreg: Ops, rightly so, several of the images that are in this post did not come out (:, hopefully the rest of the users who have responded to the topic update it. To all this, I have not been able to obtain the same result in his answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58740/7832), perhaps I am the one who does not understand the instructions well.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL The best thing is to ***never*** use tabs.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I accepted a couple of edits to other posts, not this one as I don't think being able to copy tabs from here is useful.

Comment: @egreg OK, it's the bad habit of direct copy/compiling :).

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL If not in a verbatim context, I advocate using `^^I` for tab characters, because with that tabs are easier to spot, it doesn't break with the site's rendering and also the code can be copy-pasted directly

Answer (score 3):

**REVISED ANSWER**

I discovered that even though I was copy and pasting a TAB into TeXworks, the editor itself was doing a conversion to spaces in my ORIGINAL ANSWER.  Thus, I used a different editor which I knew would preserve the TAB character in the file, and it shows that the keyboard TAB behaves like the `^^I` "TeX TAB"...almost.

If the TAB is not at the line end, then the "keyboard-TAB" and "TeX-TAB" behave identically.  If however, the TAB is at the end-of-line, the "keyboard TAB" is treated as a space, whereas the "TeX TAB" is still treated however redefined by TeX.

Conclusions:

1. Keyboard TABS and TeX-TABs (`^^I`) seem to be treated the same, *except at the end of input lines.*
2. Keyboard TABS are removed at the end-of-line (what David said), whereas `^^I` TABS are not.
3. Use the TeX TAB `^^I` to denote TABS in code, as editors are prone to do auto-conversion on your keyboard TABS otherwise.

The MWE (**WARNING:** copy/pasting this MWE into your editor may result in a conversion of the tabs into spaces):

```
With the TAB as defined by \TeX\par
% TWO EXPLICIT SPACES
x\ \ x\par%
% THE FOLLOWING PUTS AN EMPTY GROUP AFTER THE "KEYBOARD-TAB"; RESULT = 2 SPACES
x   {}
x\par%
% THE FOLLOWING TRAILS WITH A KEYBOARD TAB (WHAT THE OP TRIED); RESULT = 1 SPACE
x   
x\par
% THE FOLLOWING TRAILS WITH A "TeX-TAB"; RESULT = 1 SPACE
x^^I
x\par

With the TAB as catcode 12:\par
\catcode`\^^I=12 %
% TWO EXPLICIT SPACES
x\ \ x\par%
% THE FOLLOWING PUTS AN EMPTY GROUP AFTER THE "KEYBOARD-TAB"; RESULT = TAB GLYPH + SPACE
x   {}
x\par%
% THE FOLLOWING TRAILS WITH A KEYBOARD TAB (WHAT THE OP TRIED); RESULT = 1 SPACE
x   
x\par
% THE FOLLOWING TRAILS WITH A "TeX-TAB"; RESULT = TAB GLYPH PLUS SPACE
x^^I
x\par

\catcode`\^^I=\active %
\def^^I{\space}
With the TAB as an active space

% TWO EXPLICIT SPACES
x\ \ x\par%
% THE FOLLOWING PUTS AN EMPTY GROUP AFTER THE "KEYBOARD-TAB"; RESULT = 2 SPACES
x   {}
x\par%
% THE FOLLOWING TRAILS WITH A KEYBOARD TAB (WHAT THE OP TRIED); RESULT = 1 SPACE
x   
x\par
% THE FOLLOWING TRAILS WITH A "TeX-TAB"; RESULT = 2 SPACES
x^^I
x\par

\catcode`\^^I=\active %
\def^^I{Q}
With the TAB as an active Q

% TWO EXPLICIT SPACES
x\ \ x\par%
% THE FOLLOWING PUTS AN EMPTY GROUP AFTER THE "KEYBOARD-TAB"; RESULT = Q +  SPACE
x   {}
x\par%
% THE FOLLOWING TRAILS WITH A KEYBOARD TAB (WHAT THE OP TRIED); RESULT = 1 SPACE
x   
x\par
% THE FOLLOWING TRAILS WITH A "TeX-TAB"; RESULT = Q + SPACE
x^^I
x\par

\bye
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (AS FOOLED BY MY EDITOR)**

The original answer was removed, because I was fooled by my editor when pasting a TAB into the input file...the editor did an auto-conversion to spaces.

---

I should note the TeXbook talks about the TAB character, as noted in my comments to the OP, on pages 8, 45, 369-370, and 391.

Comment: Firstly I'd like to thank you for taking the time to read, ponder, and attempt to answer my question. However, I'm not going to accept your answer, and here's why. Regarding conclusion #1: my question was specifically about trailing tabs that are entered literally, not about any other kind of tabs. Regarding conclusion #2: this conclusion was the *premise* of my question; the question is: why does this conclusion hold, considering the TeXbook implicitly precludes it. Regarding conclusion #3: This is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @EvanAad I understand completely.  It was a much a learning exercise for me.  To some extent, my answer is just a collection of what I learned, which, as you note, did not resolve your issue.  I thank you for putting up with my ramblings.

Comment: @EvanAad Mildly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311172/does-the-tab-key-do-anything

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Hi, maybe you can modify your example file whit real `TAB`s using the tip given by Ulrich Diez at (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508103/7832) that is somehow related.

Answer (score 3):

If you typeset a character 9 using the default plain tex font encoding you get a capital greek letter (all the Greek uppercase letters are in the ascii control code slots in cm fonts)

[image]

```
\catcode9=12\relax% ASCII 9 is tab


[   ]% tab (which will be converted to space by this site)

[ ]



\bye
```

the tabs are removed from ends of lines before tokenisation actually the default `input_ln` function in `tex.web` only strips spaces

```
    if buffer[last-1]<>" " then last_nonblank:=last;
```

But file handling is one of the few system-dependent tex features, and web2c based TeX also strip tab.

Comment: This is all well and good, but not what I asked. Your last sentence is the *premise* of my question. My question is: how can this be explained, considering the TeXbook implicitly states otherwise.

Comment: @EvanAad the TeXBook says: `Another noteworthy characteristic of this manual is that it doesn't
always tell the ^{truth}.`  You need to read tex.web not the texbook, but actually that seems to just be looking for space not space or tab, so I may adjust my answer later. Just looking...

Comment: Seems to me that @EvanAad is trying to find all the lies; I hope he gets all the jokes.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior has been confirmed as a bug by [David Fuchs](https://tug.org/interviews/fuchs.html), and TeX Live's [Karl Berry](http://tug.org/interviews/berry.html) has told me it would be fixed in web2c. [Julian Gilbey](https://people.debian.org/~jdg/) traced the bug to the same source as Heiko Oberdiek did in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389090/21685).

Here's what Mr. Fuchs had to say about this bug.

> [...] yes this does seem to be porting bug; the correct output
>   consists of two lines: "dot space space dot", "dot PSI space dot".
>   (The upper-case PSI character is in position 9 of cmr10, and the tab
>   character is 9 in ascii, of course, and the first line of the input
>   file sets the catcode to make tabs be typeset.)
>
> A slight subtlety is that TeX as specified exactly in Volume B does
>   not accept any characters below `<space>`, including `<tab>`, at all; so
>   pure? / minimalist? / fundamental? / nominal? TeX on this input simply
>   grouses about the tab right away:
>
> ! Text line contains an invalid character.l.3 .^^?
>
> But module 23 is very explicit on the proper way to "get the most
>   permissive character set", which every port typically does, and it's
>   in that context that the claim of "correct behavior" above is made.
>
> Finally, one might wonder why TeX strips trailing spaces and nothing
>   else, including tabs. The answer is that originally it didn't strip
>   anything. But there were systems we wanted to support (particularly
>   IBM's OS360 and VM/CMS) that had fixed-record conventions for text
>   files. So, typically, moving a .tex file to an IBM mainframe caused
>   each line to be padded out to 80 characters by the system adding
>   trailing space characters. We wanted to make sure that any round-trip
>   to/from such systems would not create an input file that had any
>   chance of a mysterious change of behavior between platforms (in, say,
>   some verbatim mode), and the best solution was to have TeX always
>   ignore trailing space characters, so that it would be immune to them
>   automagically appearing. But there was no reason to strip any other
>   characters, including tab.

Comment: Nice. That's what i said too, about “nominal” TeX (as in Volume B) saying `Text line contains an invalid character` on tabs. How did you get in touch with these people?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yes you did mention it. Well observed. All I did was post a bug report to the tex-k mailing list from the [tug.org mailing lists](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/). First Julian replied, then Karl, and Karl contacted David and let me know of his reply.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple matters here that have been brought up in various iterations of the question, comments, and answers:

1. what TeX does with trailing tabs at the end of a line
2. *after reading in lines,* how TeX treats tabs
3. how the visual width of a space is affected by the font
4. how TeX treats punctuation, specifically the `.`

I know your ultimate question is only about the first one, so let's get the other things out of the way first.

Consider the following test file, which is intended to illustrate the same points as your example:

```
\def\test{
a b

a\ b

a\ \ b

% There's a tab in the line below
a   b

% There's a tab at the end of the line below
a   
b
}

\def\testdot{
. .

.\ .

.\ \ .

% There's a tab in the line below
.   .

% There's a tab at the end of the line below
.   
.
}

\test

\testdot

\vskip 1em \hrule \vskip 1em

\font\myfont=cmtt14\myfont

\test

\testdot

\end
```

This produces:

[image: output]

Note that the `.`s behave differently from the a-b example except in the cases with explicit spaces (`.\ .` and `.\ \ .`). However, these differences are just because TeX typesets a larger space after sentences for typographic reasons (and all these differences go away if you add `\frenchspacing`), so we might as well work with just simple letters to avoid that confusion.

So with that out of the way, here is a simpler case:

```
\catcode9=12

% There's a tab in the line below
a   b

% There's a tab at the end of the line below
a   
b

\end
```

produces:

[image: simpler]

> **Conclusion**: Trailing tabs are removed when reading a line.

---

Now your remaining question is *why* this is so, and whether this is consistent with Knuth's intentions as stated in either *The TeXbook* or the TeX program (aka Volume A and Volume B).

In section 31 of the TeX program is the `input_ln` procedure which reads in lines. He says “trailing blanks are removed”.

[image: input_ln, part 1]

He also says this is something TeX implementations are encouraged to rewrite and optimize:

[image: input_ln, part 2]

His own implementation is something that strips any trailing character whose *xord* is 32 (the fact that `" "` which appears as [image] below actually means `32` is an aspect of WEB and string pool files…):

[image: input_ln, part 3]

Note the `xord` there: it converts any character to an integer. And in the "official" implementation as in the book, the question of tabs in the input file has a simpler answer: they are treated as invalid:

[image: xord system-dependent]

Strictly speaking this means that if you had a hypothetical TeX implementation straight out of `tex.web` and with absolutely no system-dependent changes so that it used `tex.web`'s implementation of `input_ln` and the same `xord` array (even Knuth never used such an implementation), then you couldn't even *have* a tab character in your file, *anywhere*: it would have an `xord` of `invalid_code` = 127, and when TeX encountered it, it would throw an error. (You can still see such an error by introducing byte 127 in a file: the error message is `! Text line contains an invalid character.`)

As Heiko's answer points out, the `web2c` implementation of TeX as used in TeX Live implements `input_ln` in C for speed, as suggested by Knuth in section 31. It strips both trailing spaces and trailing tabs. This is consistent with a certain interpretation of "trailing blanks are removed" (which is probably why the change was considered ok). Note that by itself, it's not automatically inconsistent with the TeXbook on p. 46 saying that “TeX deletes any ⟨space⟩ characters (number 32) that occur at the right end of an input line” — that only refers to what happens *after* the file's bytes are translated using `xord`. This is what Knuth means when on pp. 44–45 of *The TeXbook* it says:

> the people who installed your local TeX system can tell you the
>   correspondence between what you type and the character number that TeX receives

So deleting these trailing tabs would have been perfectly consistent with the `tex.web` code of `input_ln` (and what's described in The TeXbook above), *if* its `xord` had been set up so that tabs are *always* treated as spaces (this is not the case). Instead, it follows a setting of `xord` and `xchr` where it appears *all* bytes are allowed in files and (other than a newline) byte N is read by TeX as N (nothing else gets translated to `invalid_code`). For curiosity, I created a file containing `a<character C><newline>b` for every non-printable character C from 0 to 127 (that is: 0 to 31, and 127). I also added a few `\catcode` instructions so that all of these (except for `13`) have catcode 12. This is the result:

```
% xxd -g 1 -c 24 mwe.tex
00000000: 5c 63 61 74 63 6f 64 65 30 3d 31 32 0a 5c 63 61 74 63 6f 64 65 31 3d 31  \catcode0=12.\catcode1=1
00000018: 32 0a 5c 63 61 74 63 6f 64 65 39 3d 31 32 0a 5c 63 61 74 63 6f 64 65 31  2.\catcode9=12.\catcode1
00000030: 31 3d 31 32 0a 5c 63 61 74 63 6f 64 65 31 32 3d 31 32 0a 5c 63 61 74 63  1=12.\catcode12=12.\catc
00000048: 6f 64 65 31 34 3d 31 32 0a 5c 63 61 74 63 6f 64 65 31 32 37 3d 31 32 0a  ode14=12.\catcode127=12.
00000060: 61 00 0a 62 0a 0a 61 01 0a 62 0a 0a 61 02 0a 62 0a 0a 61 03 0a 62 0a 0a  a..b..a..b..a..b..a..b..
00000078: 61 04 0a 62 0a 0a 61 05 0a 62 0a 0a 61 06 0a 62 0a 0a 61 07 0a 62 0a 0a  a..b..a..b..a..b..a..b..
00000090: 61 08 0a 62 0a 0a 61 09 0a 62 0a 0a 61 0b 0a 62 0a 0a 61 0c 0a 62 0a 0a  a..b..a..b..a..b..a..b..
000000a8: 61 0d 0a 62 0a 0a 61 0e 0a 62 0a 0a 61 0f 0a 62 0a 0a 61 10 0a 62 0a 0a  a..b..a..b..a..b..a..b..
000000c0: 61 11 0a 62 0a 0a 61 12 0a 62 0a 0a 61 13 0a 62 0a 0a 61 14 0a 62 0a 0a  a..b..a..b..a..b..a..b..
000000d8: 61 15 0a 62 0a 0a 61 16 0a 62 0a 0a 61 17 0a 62 0a 0a 61 18 0a 62 0a 0a  a..b..a..b..a..b..a..b..
000000f0: 61 19 0a 62 0a 0a 61 1a 0a 62 0a 0a 61 1b 0a 62 0a 0a 61 1c 0a 62 0a 0a  a..b..a..b..a..b..a..b..
00000108: 61 1d 0a 62 0a 0a 61 1e 0a 62 0a 0a 61 1f 0a 62 0a 0a 61 7f 0a 62 0a 0a  a..b..a..b..a..b..a..b..
00000120: 5c 65 6e 64 0a                                                           \end.
```

[image: output for all bytes]

**Summary**:

- In the `web2c` implementation of C, the `xord` of having byte `c` in the input file results in TeX receiving input code `c`. (This is allowed by Knuth's conventions: appendix C of *The TeXbook* is entirely about this kind of thing.)
- In the `web2c` implementation of C, trailing spaces and tabs are removed. This is inconsistent with what is described in *The TeXbook*, though it *would* have been consistent if the `xord` of a tab character were 32. (Though in that case `plain.tex`'s definition of `` \catcode`\^^I=10 `` would have been mostly unnecessary (applying only when someone explicitly wrote `^^I` in their input file), as a tab character in the input file would already be read by `input_ln` as a space.)

Comment: Thanks. The point about French spacing was enlightening. I also agree with your final two conclusions. Regarding the other points...

Comment: 1. You wrote: 'In section 31 of the TeX program is the input_ln procedure which reads in lines. He says “trailing blanks are removed”.' When Knuth writes "blanks", he means "␣", as he makes clear in no uncertain terms in the formula at the end of the very sentence from which the above quote was excerpted. As for what "␣" means - see 3 below.

Comment: 2. You wrote: "He also says this is something TeX implementations are encouraged to rewrite and optimize". In the quote you cited he clarifies exactly what optimization is allowed ("special routines that read in an entire array of characters at once") and what its purpose is ("to reduce system overhead"). Removing trailing tabs is not an "optimization" that falls under these criteria.

Comment: 3. You wrote: 'His own implementation is something that strips any trailing character whose xord is 32 (the fact that " " which appears as "␣" below actually means 32 is an aspect of WEB and string pool files…):' I disagree with your interpretation. "␣" means "the space character, in whatever encoding the Pascal system used to compile the source code is set up to use". See section 21 on p. 11. If Knuth wanted to write `buffer[last - 1] ≠ xord['40]`, he would have done so.

Comment: 4. You wrote: 'And in the "official" implementation as in the book, the question of tabs in the input file has a simpler answer: they are treated as invalid'. Yes, I agree with you on this. An interesting observation, but not relevant to the question at hand, since the question would not have been possible on a system where the tab was treated by TeX as invalid.

Comment: 5. You wrote: 'the web2c implementation of TeX [...] strips both trailing spaces and trailing tabs. This is consistent with a certain interpretation of "trailing blanks are removed"'. It is only consistent with an invalid interpretation of "trailing blanks are removed", as pointed out in 1 above. In other words, it is not consistent with Knuth's specifications.

Comment: 6. You wrote: 'Note that by itself, it's not automatically inconsistent with the TeXbook on p. 46 saying that “TeX deletes any ⟨space⟩ characters (number 32) that occur at the right end of an input line” — that only refers to what happens after the file's bytes are translated using xord.' Yes, I guess you are technically correct. It cannot be precluded that some absent-minded system administrator will set up the xord array in such a way as to map OS `<tab>` to ASCII `<space>`. However, this is not the case on my system, nor on yours, as the experiment in the end of your answer demonstrates.

Comment: 7. Thanks for your thoughtful and detailed post. It is always a pleasure to read your answers. :)

Comment: Regarding point 5: I've changed my mind a little. Maybe you have a point that the quote from the TeXbook is consistent with a certain admissible interpretation of "trailing blanks are removed", namely: if `xord` maps OS tabs to ASCII spaces. And `xord` doesn't seem to have any restrictions about how it should map non-visible characters (other than spaces). However, when `xord` maps only the OS space to the ASCII space, as is the default for TeX Live, there's no question about how to interpret the above quote, as you mentioned in your 2nd conclusion.

Comment: @EvanAad Thanks. I mostly agree with your comments; I only have a comment about your (3): when you run `tangle` on `tex.web`, it turns the line `if buffer[last - 1] ≠ "␣"` into `if buffer[last-1]<>32` — the fact that `" "` means `32` (on all systems) is a feature of WEB. So the double-quoted string `" "` doesn't really mean “the space character, in whatever encoding the Pascal system used to compile the source code is set up to use”, although the single-quoted `' '` means exactly what you said. (But again, this 32 is after `xord` has converted the file's character to an integer…)

Comment: I stand corrected.