# Why does a newline character still disappear even with other/active catcode set?

Tags: macros, expl3

For example, with this code

```latex
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\char_set_catcode_other:N \%
\tl_set:Nn\var{%}
\tl_analysis_show:N\var
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The output is

```
The token list \var contains the tokens:
>  % (the character %).
```

as expected, and it also works with all the other special characters. However when I try it with the newline character (which is encoded with the byte with value 10 on UNIX)

```
\char_set_catcode_other:n {10}
\tl_set:Nn\var{
}
\tl_analysis_show:N\var
```

the output is

```
The token list \var is empty
```

Why is that happening? (also `^^J` or `^^M` results in the same output, while a literal newline results in the output below)

```
The token list \var contains the tokens:
>    (the character  ).
```

Comment: See also: [tex core - New lines and TeX: difference between ^^J and ^^M - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8967/new-lines-and-tex-difference-between-j-and-m?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Also: for the same reason, `\<literal new line character>` is not the same thing as `\^^J` or `\^^M`. The latter is useful when e.g. you want to have the escape sequence for passing to `\string` or `\regex_replace_all:NNn` to *replace something with literal new line character*.

Comment: See also: [spacing - Why doesn't a trailing tab typeset? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389030/why-doesnt-a-trailing-tab-typeset) – caused by the same reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` the value of `\endlinechar` is set to 32 (space) and the category code of the space is set to 9 (ignored).

Thus your code is equivalent to `\tl_set:Nn \var {}` and the token list is indeed empty.

Setting the category code of the Unix newline (character 10) is irrelevant, because this character appears nowhere: when TeX reads a record (a line of input) it immediately discards the end-of-record operating system specific character and replaces it with the `\endlinechar`.